# Scheduling recurring tasks in Java without them stopping on unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, task, timertask

I have a very simple Runnable that I want to schedule for execution every 30 seconds - bear in mind that this is just a simple example for this question's sake and not the actual point of using this in reality.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Throwing an unchecked exception on purpose...");
    int abc = 123 - 123;
    int def = 123 / abc;
}
```

I was using Timer and TimerTask but ran into a problem: whenever the TimerTask raised an unchecked exception, any subsequent execution of that task would be cancelled; thus the task above would actually only run once because it would throw an unchecked division by 0 Exception.

As far as I know, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor has the exact same "feature", at least according to the official Java API documentation "If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed".

Is there any standard way in Java to make either Timer or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to don't suppress subsequent executions if an unchecked exception is raised?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to use a try/catch statement and catch the exception.

Comment: @DMB3 I might be slow, but why catching this RuntimeException would be a bad thing?

Comment: The code inside the specific Runnable may be implemented outside of the project and thus we don't have access to the code to catch exceptions there. The wrapper solution proposed by Jon Skeet obviously accomplishes this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any standard way in Java to make either Timer or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to don't suppress subsequent executions if an unchecked exception is raised?

Well there's one *really simple* way - create an `ExceptionSuppressingRunnable` which wraps another one:

```
public final class ExceptionSuppressingRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private final Runnable original;

    public ExceptionSuppressingRunnable(Runnable runnable)
    {
        // TODO: Null validation
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            original.run();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            // TODO: Logging
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this deliberately doesn't catch `Error` (or any other non-Exception subclass of Throwable). You *could* catch `Exception` instead of `RuntimeException` - it would only make a difference in weird cases where code threw a checked exception without declaring it (due to byte code rewriting, versioning differences or whatever). I think it's probably clearer to just catch `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Yeah obviously having a try/catch around the whole code kinda solves it but I was more thinking in terms of not having to actually do that. But this works, obviously.

Comment: @DMB3: This puts the behaviour in a *single* place (very simply) without any dependency on a particular timer etc. It separates the concern of "suppressing and logging exceptions" from "regularly running a particular task".

Comment: True. This does work and I guess there's no point in trying to find more obscure alternatives. Thanks.